# TMPDIR is not set in a new shell when using su

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

On a Mac running macOS 13.5, `$TMPDIR` is not set in a new shell. This is a multi-user machine, and it is unset for all users that are `su`ed to, causing multiple issues since libraries may default to `/tmp`, which is not writable by everyone.

The Mac with the problem is accessed via SSH through one account, and when I change to another account using:

```
sudo su - otheruser
```

I get an environment without `TMPDIR`. Now, I understand that `sudo su` discards environment variables; this is fine! I don't want the `sudo`ing user's temporary directory, but the one of the user being accessed.

How can I accomplish that?

Note that it works when I SSH into the target user directly.

Comment: Does it work if you use `sudo -s -u otheruser`?

Comment: That results in all sorts of permission-related errors and no environment variable set.